# What are commonly used database types?

Tags: datatypes

There are a lot of database types. Can you list a list of the top classification of databases commonly found in schools and offices? Any help is appreciated. Hope to see compressed and summarized type as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this list of mine :

1. Employee/ Student Information
2. Account Receivable/Payable
3. Attendance Record
4. Inventory
5. Class/Task Records

Hope this list helps. For further reference, you can try to look at this : http://www.techyv.com/article/most-used-database